# Can't print UIWebView with text color. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, printing, uiwebview, airprint

I have a `UIWebView`. I want to print the contents of it using AirPrint. I came up with this code:

```
@IBAction func print(_ sender: Any) {
    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.general
    printInfo.jobName = "some name"
    printController.printInfo = printInfo

    let formatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter()

    formatter.perPageContentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 72, left: 72, bottom: 72, right: 72)
    printController.printFormatter = formatter

    printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

When I run the app, a print interaction controller and everything works.

However, I have things like these in the html because I want to emphasize some text:

```
<span style="color: #ff0000">some text</span>
```

"some text" appears red in the web view, but it is black when I look at the preview in the print interaction controller! In other words, all the colors are gone!

I tried to change the HTML to:

```
<span style="background: #ff0000">some text</span>
```

but the print preview appears the same. I was very surprised because the `<hr>` and `<h3>` tags all rendered fine in the preview.

Is there a way to print colored text?

Notes:

- I *did* select the "Simulated Color Laser Printer"
- I know I can take a screenshot of the webview and print it. But wouldn't that print only the part of the HTML that's showing on the screen?

Comment: I just set up a HTML page with the exact span you have quoted, loaded it in a UIWebView and printed it using your print code, and I'm seeing red text. There appears to be something else causing the problem. Can you perhaps provide a link to the actual website which isn't printing?

Comment: @CraigGrummitt Sorry but I can't seem to edit the question. Here is a pastebin link to the edit that I was trying to make: http://pastebin.com/raw/B87WUivY

Comment: Apple has some code to turn HTML to PDF. I haven't tried it, but maybe it will solve your problems https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/4f3d0f33df3ca96764ccac72a2dda729a567ac33/ResearchKit/Common/ORKHTMLPDFWriter.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this section of your CSS:

```
@media print {
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

This `@media print` section defines extra rules for how your content looks when it is printed. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

Within this section you have a `*:after` element which applies content after every element on your page. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_after.asp)

Within the `*:after` section you declare a color of black (`#000`), even making doubly sure of black, by declaring this color as `!important` - giving this declaration more weight than any declaration of color in the element itself. [link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

So you have several options for resolving this:

1. Simply remove the `!important` tag from the color line:

   color: #000;
2. Remove the whole color line from your CSS.
3. Remove the *:after section from your CSS.
4. Remove the @media print section from your CSS.

It all depends on what you were specifically after.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that you can define how the page looks when printed in css! I will try that!